# Problem with the definition of the Cissoid of Diocles

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, plane-curves

As per the definition given on this [site](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CissoidofDiocles.html),

Given an origin O and a point P on the curve, let B be the point where the extension of the line OP intersects the line $x=2a$ and C be the intersection of the circle of radius $a$ and center $(a,0)$ with the extension of OP. Then the Cissoid of Diocles is the curve which satisfies OP=CB.

[image]

But is this condition applicable to the points on the curve that lie outside the circle? Clearly, if point 'P' was outside the circle, then the extension of OP wouldn't have intersected the circle.

What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: A richer reference for this curve (and in general for many other curves) is https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/cissoiddroite/cissoiddroite.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$OP$ is considered part of its own extension, so for $P$ outside the circle, $C$ is between $O$ and $P$ (and the required equality may be restated as $OC=PB$). There is thus no problem in the definition.

Comment: I get your first point — that the point $C$ will be between $O$ and $P$, but are you sure that the required equality has to be restated to $OC =PB$? Wouldn't the original condition $OP = CB$ still work?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser Yes, I never said the original won't work, only that it may be restated that way (which does not involve overlapping line segments).

Comment: Okay, I get it now. $OP = CB \iff OC = PB$.